# Detecting closed walks that visit a given edge

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to indicate whether an edge is part of a closed walk in an undirected graph only by looking at its adjacency matrix and using only matrix powers and linear algebra?

---

My approach:

Given adjacency matrix $A$ for graph $G$, we denote the edge between nodes $v_i$ and $v_j$ as $\varepsilon_{i, j}$. For $\varepsilon_{i, j}$ not to be in a closed loop, we need to have
$$
A_{i,j}=1
$$
and
$$
A^2_{i,j}+A^3_{i,j}+\dots+A^n_{i,j}=0
$$
where $n$ is the size of graph. However, that includes paths that contain $\varepsilon_{i, j}$. To that end, we can use Roberts approach below:

> Let $B$ be obtained from the adjacency matrix $A$ by setting  the
> $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ entries to $0$.

Then I need to compute a new matrix $B$ for each element $(i,j)$ in A, compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} B^k$. However, that is way too expensive. Is there a method that is computationally less expensive, at least to be able to compute it without n^3 loops?

Comment: Say $e=vw$  Is $v-e-w-e-v$ a closed walk?

Comment: @saulspatz No. Wouldn't then any edge be a part of a closed walk?

Comment: @Yes, that's why I'm asking.  What's the definition of a closed walk?

Comment: @saulspatz To have another path from $v$ to $w$ except for $v-e-w$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to know if there's a $v_i, v_j$-walk in the graph $G - \varepsilon_{i,j}$ whose adjacency matrix is $B$.

The method that adds up $B + B^2 + \dots + B^{n-1}$ works because the $(i,j)$ entry of $B^k$ counts the number of walks of length $k$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$. If any such walk exists, there is one of length $n-1$ or less.

Without using that last fact, we could keep going forever, and take the infinite sum $I + B + B^2 + B^3 + \dots$ (throwing in the identity to make things simpler). The infinite sum is just equal to $(I-B)^{-1}$, if it converges; unfortunately, it's not going to converge.

However, since we don't care about the value of the $(i,j)$ entry and only whether it's nonzero, we can replace $B$ by a small multiple of $B$. In particular, if we replace $B$ by $\frac1n B$, then $I + \frac1n B + (\frac1n B )^2 + (\frac1n B )^3 + \dots$ is guaranteed to converge, and it will converge to $(I - \frac1n B)^{-1}$.

Therefore it's enough to check if $(I - \frac1n B)^{-1}$ has a nonzero $(i,j)$ entry.

Some further simplifications: instead of $(I - \frac1n B)$, we could invert $nI - B$. Instead of computing the $(i,j)$ entry of $(nI - B)^{-1}$, we can compute the $(i,j)$ entry of [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{adj}(nI - B) = \det(nI - B)(nI - B)^{-1}$. This is given by the $(i,j)$ cofactor of $nI - B$, which is the determinant of an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix.

Comment: $(I-B)^{-1}$ does not converge because $|B|<1$ may not hold. How can you tell $|(1/n) B|<1$ holds?

Comment: An entry of $B^k$ counts closed walks between two vertices, and there's at most roughly $(n-1)^{k-2}$ of these, so if we scale down by $n^k$, we get something bounded above by a geometric series.

Comment: Another essentially equivalent way to put it: all eigenvalues of $B$ are bounded in absolute value by the maximum degree, which is at most $n-1$, so all eigenvalues of $\frac1n B$ are at most $1 - \frac1n < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be obtained from the adjacency matrix $A$ by setting  the $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ entries to $0$ (i. e. the adjacency matrix of the graph obtained by deleting edge $ij$). The edge $ij$ is part of a closed walk iff $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (B^k)_{i,j} = 0$, where the graph has $n$ vertices.

Comment: Are you sure the summation index and matrix index are both $j$? I just submitted an edit changing summation index and the matrix power to $k$.